# How Replace All img src With data-src for Lazy Load Without jQuery

Tags: javascript, image, attributes, src

I want to make the images lazy load, for that it is very important to have data-src. That's why I need a Javascript code which is removes src and add data-src.

By the way i was applied this code but it's not work properly

```js
var imgEl = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for (var i=0; i<imgEl.length; i++) {
    if(imgEl[i].getAttribute('src')) {
       imgEl[i].setAttribute('data-src',imgEl[i].getAttribute('src'));
       imgEl[i].removeAttribute('src');
    }
}
```

```html
<img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/07/03/10/28/waterfall-5365926__340.jpg" alt="img">
```

Comment: By "not work properly" do you mean that images load then hide away, or that images load entirely

Comment: Based off of the snippet, it appears to be working

Comment: means it works but not load in lazy

Comment: and i need that type short js code which is remove src or replace with data-src

Comment: It does lazy load. Look in the network tab: once the script runs, the request is cancelled and no image data is loaded https://imgur.com/a/arUnNND

Comment: You need to replace src with data-src on backend and not in the browser

Comment: Yes I need backend and browser both please give me another Script like i given

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you use the `IntersectionObserver`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

Place your source in a `data-src` attribute on the `<img/>` tag and let the browser decide when to load it.

1. Initalize the Observer

```
try {
  IO = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
    entries.forEach((entry) => {
      const lazyImage = entry.target;
      if (typeof entry.isIntersecting !== "undefined") {
        if (entry.isIntersecting && !lazyImage.src) {
          lazyImage.src = lazyImage.dataset.src;
        }
      } else {
        lazyImage.src = lazyImage.dataset.src;
      }
    });
  });
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
}
```

2. When page loads, tell the Observer what to watch.

```
[...document.querySelectorAll('img[data-src]')].forEach(function (el) {
  IO.observe(el);
});
```

There are a lot of other options in the API to control the threshold for when the browser loads the image.  I use it in all of my projects and it works great with the default options.

Comment: but how i place source in data-src? i want a script which is remove src and place data-src. Lazy load script will work only when data-src is added. That's why i need a script by which I can replace or add src to data-src. Because I can't add manually.

Comment: Exactly the best answer could be using Intersection observer API

Comment: I don't understand why you can't add the data-src attribute to your images.  If you can add src then you can certainly add data-src (or any other data-* attribute).  Let the Intersection Observer take care of transferring data-src to src when it's time.

Comment: Please Modify the script which i given